# Presenting a nuclear reaction in LaTeX

Tags: equations, mhchem

I wanted to know what is the best way to present a nuclear reaction with the exponents and index of the atoms A and Z being in front of the element?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your question clearer to us by (1) adding a minimal compilable code and (2) a sketch of what you want, because, unfortunately, we are not all physicists.

Comment: `mhchem` was written to solve your problem.

Comment: As an addition to  the previous comment: You might want to have a look at page 6 of the mhchem manual (section Isotopes). An example from the manual: `\ce{^{227}_{90}Th+}`)

Comment: Could you please give a green check to mnchem's best answer, please? In my opinion the best answer, in this case is from the other user. Thank you.

Comment: I like correctness and I thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Isotope equation as rendered by mhchem]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\section{The discovery of \ce{^4_2He}}
$\ce{^4_2He + ^27_13Al -> ^31_15P -> ^30_15P + ^1_0n}$

\sffamily Works also with text fonts (\ce{^4_2He}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the recent edit.

Answer (score 5):

For a special nuclear reaction in LaTeX, I have taken a particular reaction here into this link https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/latex-help-for-nuclear-reactions.14912/ using [`isotope`](https://ctan.org/pkg/isotope) package. I use often this solution just as alternative to `mhchem` package.

**EDIT**: --> for the comment of the user @mhchem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Text mode: \textcolor{red}{\isotope[4][2]{He}} or normal without color \isotope[4][2]{He} and also for the section.
\section{The discovery of \isotope[4][2]{He}}

In math-mode you can have the same thing:

$\isotope[4][2]{He}+\isotope[27][13]{Al}\rightarrow\isotope[31][15]{P}\rightarrow\isotope[30][15]{P}+\isotope[1][0]{n}$
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**:

Also `isotope` package can have a bold formula in the section in text mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{isotope}

\begin{document}

\section{The discovery of \isotope[4][2]{He}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\isotope` is not properly working with text fonts. Try adding `\sffamily` to the code (or do `\section{The discovery of \isotope[4][2]{He}}`), and you'll see that it will use math font.

Comment: @mhchem Kind user, I hope I understand your comment. Thank you for the report received. My best regards.